# php Encryption not work in 5.6 or later version?

Tags: php, encryption

I am using this code to encrypt password but it doesn't work php 5.6 or later versions. Please suggest me new code without changing algo.

please give me new code without changing algorithm.

```
<?php
class Encryption {
    var $skey = "844958uyjd875e89t5f4h6j4h5g"; // you can change it

    public function safe_b64encode($string) {
        $data = base64_encode($string);
        $data = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$data);
        return $data;
    }

    public function safe_b64decode($string) {
        $data = str_replace(array('-','_'),array('+','/'),$string);
        $mod4 = strlen($data) % 4;
        if ($mod4) {
            $data .= substr('====', $mod4);
        }
        return base64_decode($data);
    }

    public function encode($value){ 
        if(!$value){return false;}
        $text = $value;
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($this->safe_b64encode($crypttext)); 
    }

    public function decode($value){
        if(!$value){return false;}
        $crypttext = $this->safe_b64decode($value); 
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($decrypttext);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why would one want to encrypt a password such way?!?

Comment: What does _"doesn't work"_ mean? Errors? Wrong result? Either way. **you should _never_ store encrypted passwords.** That's a major security risk. You should _only_ save password hashes!

Comment: First check that mcrypt is installed or not?. if it is not installed then install it form third party.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I doubt this is for storage. Looks more like a solution to transfer a password because if the 64bit encoding. That is why I asked for the purpose.

Comment: php-mcrypt installed?

Comment: @arkascha I've stopped assuming anything about peoples ideas when it comes to security, so it's better to give an extra warning. :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That is a hard life you are going to face based on that assumption ;-)

Comment: @Shivam Pandey What is that  doesn't work? What's the error that you see? What are your inputs and outputs?

Comment: actually if i use above code in php version 5.3 it works but if use with php version 5.6 it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `password_hash` and `password_verify`. It's the safest way to protect passwords.
For example:

```
$password_hash = password_hash("yourpassword", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (password_verify('yourpassword', $password_hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php